# L2 and L1 norm inverse relationship for bounded functions

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I would like to know whether $\|f\|_{L^2}\leq\mu(X)^{1/2}\|f\|_{L^1}$ for bounded functions. I can show an opposite relation given a finite measure space using Holder's Inequality, but I am interested in an inverse relation, even if there are constants that need to be added/multiplied.

I do not think that this question is a duplicate. I am aware that there are counterexamples for the general case where the function is not bounded, such as:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
but I have seen people mention that the inequality holds true for functions with no singularities.

Intuitively it does make sense to me but I am having trouble trying to prove it, and I could not find any reference to that in books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|f(x)|^2 \leq \|f\|_{L^\infty}\,|f(x)|$,
$$
\|f\|_{L^2} = \left(\int |f(x)|^2\,\mathrm d x\right)^{1/2} \leq \left(\int \|f\|_{L^\infty}|f(x)|\,\mathrm d x\right)^{1/2} = \|f\|_{L^\infty}^{1/2}\, \|f\|_{L^1}^{1/2}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\|f\|_{L^2} \leq \|f\|_{L^\infty} + \|f\|_{L^1}.
$$

Comment: I also got to this point, but this doesn't translate to an inequality between $\|f\|_{L^2},\|f\|_{L^1} $ the way I wanted. We would need to have $\|f\|_{L^1} \geq 1$ in order to get
 $$\|f\|_{L^2}\leq\|f\|_{L^\infty}^{1/2}\|f\|_{L^1}$$

Comment: This last inequality is not possible in whole generality as this would not be homogeneous. Just replace $f$ by $\lambda f$ to see that. Similarly, your first inequality in your question is false as you could replace $f$ by $x\mapsto f(\lambda x)$

Comment: Another way to understand it is that if your first inequality was true, then one can just take a sequence of bounded functions converging to $1/\sqrt x$ and you will see that the ratio of the norms will blow up. This is related to the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: You are right. It was indeed a typo in my original post. I should've multiplied the right hand side by $\mu(X)^{1/2}$. My problem  is finding if there can be an inequality of the form:
$$\|f|\|_{L^2}\leq A+B\|f|\|_{L^1}$$

for some constants $A,B$.

Comment: Then yes since $ab\leq a^2+b^2$. I added it to the answer.